# array split with overlap

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to split arrays into multiple arrays with overlapping

```
given = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

There are two parameter, w=2 (step size is 2), m=1 (overlap 1 element)

```
[1,2,3],
[3,4,5],
[5,6,7],
[7,8,9],
```

opposed to regular `np.split_array(l, range(1,8,2))`

```
[array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([4, 5]), array([6, 7]), array([8, 9])]
```

Maybe I could do split twice, one with at every `w` and one with every `w+m` and concatenate the arrays..

Comment: There's a new windowing function.  But you could also use repeated slices. (Split array uses slices)

Comment: With the newish, safer `as_strided`,: `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(np.arange(1,10),3)[::2]`